# Forcing Cursor To Move To One Side Of The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was wondering if this was possible? i wanted to have a link saying click me and a picture below which is also hyper linked to another page. before a user tries to hover over the click me link, the cursor should automatically move to the image before it even reaches the click me link.

by the way this is not going to be part of a real website! its just a personal thing...

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [move the mouse pointer to a specific position using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position-using-javascript)

Comment: impossible, the best you can try is an effect where you hide the real mouse at all times and replace it with a fake pointer and start recording all XY positions and then control this fake pointer as you want, but the real one can't be controlled at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You cannot control the position of the mouse. This would be every malicious hacker's dream...