# JavaScript & jquery - moveTo and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright so I'm pretty new to JavaScript coding in particular and have only been working with HTML and CSS for a few months so I apologize if this comes off as ridiculously simple.

I'm trying to use basic embedded JavaScript (jquery) to get a hyperlink to move to a new position each time you mouse over it, kind of like a cat following a laser-pointer dot.

When I run this code, the "moveAway" method doesn't appear to move the link at all when it is being hovered over. Just wondering if anyone could help identify the problem here:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Sheet references -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="link">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click!</a>
</div>

<script>
function moveAway()
{
$('#link').moveTo(0,100);
}
$('#link').hover(moveAway);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find the `moveTo()` function in the jquery or jquery-ui docs. Is that from a plugin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307172/forcing-cursor-to-move-to-one-side-of-the-page huh `:)` wonder why you wanna use it! @JasonP it doesn't exist in JQ, it does in good old Javascript, Jquery can do the same using `animate` without weird behaviour. but still wonder what kind of functioanlity is this `:P`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! i didn't know of the animate tag (stupid me), but i used it and got the code functioning correctly. All the answers were great, and i even used random numbers to get the link to jump all over the page. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wanna do something like this?

You can use left and top random too.

More information in [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Sheet references -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<style>
    #link
    {
        position:absolute;
    }
</style>
<div id="link">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click!</a>
</div>

<script>
function moveAway()
{
$('#link').animate({
    left: "+=50",
    top: "+=50"
  });
}
$('#link').hover(moveAway);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#link').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('top', '0px');
    $(this).css('left', '100px');
    $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
});
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want.
See : http://jsfiddle.net/MHzYF/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a little fun by intro ducting `Math.random()` to generate `x` and `y` coordinates, and use jQuery's `animate` method. You can replace `100` with whatever offset you like.

**jQuery**

```
$('#link').on('mouseover', function(){
    x = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

    $(this).animate({
        top: x,
        left: y
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">Click!</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#link { position: absolute; }
```

[**Working Example at JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxEsp/)