# (jquery) How to freeze the mouse cursor (pointer) in an [div] element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers, mouse, block

all

For jQuery/JavaScript:

How to freeze the mouse cursor (pointer) in an [div] element?

When the user clicked the mouse button the cursor is frozen and as if the user moved a mouse the position of the cursor doesn't change.

Comment: I believe it can't be done with javascript...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing Cursor To Move To One Side Of The Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307172/forcing-cursor-to-move-to-one-side-of-the-page)

Comment: yeah no can't be done.

Comment: Actually [it is possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API), but is yet a non-standard feature.

Comment: canvas.requestPointerLock()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to "lock" or "freeze" the cursor, moving it is not possible either.

You can hide it using the css-property `cursor: none` and adding a custom cursor. However when the user is moving his cursor it will obviously not be at the same position as your custom cursor.