# Decrease mousedown sensitivity with jsignature

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousedown

I'm looking for a way to slow down the mousedown movement when drawing a signature.

I think it would allow the user more control.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I presume you would need to control the users mouse pointer. This is not possible in javascript. For reference ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position

Comment: What do you mean by mousedown movement anyway?

Comment: Are you trying to slow down the mouse speed or to slow down how often mousedown is called?

Answer (score 1):

The mousemove events are generated by the browser, and thus you can't change these.