# Magnetic cursor movement with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way when people open the web page with a couple of images and when the viewer puts his mouse in a certain area span outside of the image, the mouse is attracted to the image just like a magnet? Is it possible to do? Please suggest.

[image: magnetic effect sample image]

Comment: This may help you : [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Comment: @A.V Thank you for the link. But the image should attract the mouse pointer just like a magnet attracts iron particles if it is in a certain area span outside it. Can this be possible?

Comment: You can't move the mouse, but you could make the mouse the "magnet", and move the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't controll mouse pointer with JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing in an html page? I am not an expert on JQuery. But can JQuery do this?

Comment: Nope. You can't do it within webpage.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for any webpage to force the user's mouse to a certain location.  Allowing this would have huge malicious repercussions.

An alternative might be when the user hover's over the specified area, the image grows to fill the area.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon filed a patent regarding gravity-based links, that would, somewhat, be similar to what is discussed here...

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=8386927.PN.&OS=PN/8386927&RS=PN/8386927

I would love to see how this could be done in jQuery too, tho !

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes.** You can control mouse pointer with JavaScript.

**Here is a [very beautiful example from Codrops](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomCursors/index3.html).**
There are a lots of others you can find on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/search/pens/?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=3&q=custom%20cursor).
**Here is one: [NodeCursor](https://codepen.io/hmongouachon/pen/Ygwjrj)**.

```
$(function() {
// init plugin
NodeCursor({
    cursor: true,
    node: true,
    cursor_velocity: 1,
    node_velocity: 0.15,
    native_cursor: "none",
    element_to_hover: ".nodeHover",
    cursor_class_hover: "disable",
    node_class_hover: "expand",
    hide_mode: true,
    hide_timing: 2000
    });
});
```