# Control the mouse with keyboard javascript

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to control the mouse with keyboard (pure javascript)?
I want to allow users of my site Move the mouse cursor with the keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)