# JavaScript - set clientX and clientY

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to change the position of cursor using clientX and clientY using JavaScript. I don't want this to happen when an event fires, but whenever I want using JavaScript.

Comment: There is not, the cursor is controlled by the operating system, not the browser - sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Comment: Have you tried hiding the mouse and move an image?http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/9uczV/