# how to use javascript to move mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a very simple client side javascript code to move mouse inside browser.
That can makes lync always show "online" which makes my boss happy.
what is the good way to control mouse ?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done at all, not with current APIs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Comment: Very interested to see if this can actually be pulled off with JS :)

Comment: There must be a Lync API you can use instead to force always online? Why do you need to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: i think javascript is very small and don not need to be installed on Windows machine, which can get around of company IT department.

Comment: i have multiple fiends who think this is a very useful tool they need. but they don't want to install anything on their machine. so javascript is an good option which can be ran in browser.

Comment: Not an answer as it is not JS, but I've used this [MouseJiggle](https://mousejiggler.codeplex.com/) app in the past. It is a downloadable program, but it doesn't install which means it isn't blocked by IT policy. It moves the mouse around. There is even an option to do this without moving the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There's some pretty serious security implications of doing it. That said, you may be able to achieve your goal by [triggering](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a `mousemove` or `click` event via jQuery together with a `setInterval` to trick the page into thinking a human is interacting with it.

Comment: I think OP means that the aim is to interact with Microsoft Lync to make it seem they're always online; i.e. they're lazy but don't want their boss to find out.

Comment: Looks like there is a webapp version so I don't see what that matters? You'd just do what I said in the console directly or make a browser extension. It's not my job to judge the purpose if it's not illegal.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that Lync runs in a separate app :)