# jQuery Animate not running (or throwing error) on object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-animate

I have an en event object that I want to increase a property's value. The following code does not seem to change the properties value.

```
var e = jQuery.Event('mousemove');
e.pageX = jQuery(window).width() / 2;
jQuery(e).animate({pageX: 1000},
    {
        step: function(){
            console.log(this.pageX);
            jQuery('.mouseover').trigger(this);
        },
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'linear'
    }
);
```

Any ideas please?

*Update*
@dfsq [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bxpLpar/) and the animate function does seem to run. I don't know why this does not run in my script, and no errors are being thrown.  –

Comment: You can only animate DOM elements, not the position of the mouse cursor. What you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Anything is possible

Comment: @Alex this would be the exception that proves it ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position

Comment: MouseEvent object is read-only so changing it's properties has no effect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can set the value of e.pageX and use the event object to trigger the event. It just doesn't seem to run the animate function...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What OP is trying to do is perfectly valid and reasonable. It's not visual animation though, but object property "animation".

Comment: You code seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/9bxpLpar/

Comment: @dfsq that's right, but it's trying to move the mouse cursor. I don't see how you've come to the conclusion that this work? It's certainly not here in Chrome on OSX.

Comment: @MichaelMiriti I can set the value of the e.pageX so has write access

Comment: @dfsq That is so strange, it doesn't work in my script but it does in the fiddle. No other js errors are being thrown as far as I can tell.

Comment: Even if the animation was working, it's hard to see what `jQuery('.mouseover').trigger(this);` might be trying to achieve.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doesn't try to move the cursor, it tries to fire an event on the `.mouseover` element and specify the position it occured. (*perhaps an auto-drawing app for example*)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have a mousemove event handler that I need to set the value of the mouse position property (not the actual mouse/cursor position) occasionally.

Comment: But the signature of .trigger is `.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )` or `.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )`. Your `this` doesn't fit either signature.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 `this` would refer to the event object being worked on (as far as I'm aware). My main issue is that the property value is not being increased and `console.log` is not being called. @dfsq fiddle works though so I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: @Nate ofcource you can change these values but it has no effect besides assigning these valuse. If you want to trigger mouseover events then you should use `.trigger` as @Roamer-1888 suggested

Comment: Yes, precisely, `this` is set to the DOM element being animated.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 its not a DOM element being animated. Its an object property, and using this object to trigger the mouse event does work, and the event handler does pick up the amended object values.

Comment: @Nate, maybe you're right. I'm having trouble visualising animation of something other than a DOM element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this has to do with the version of the jQuery (*as it works on the fiddle but not if i change the jquery version*)

You could alter it a bit to work on a simple object

```
var e = jQuery.Event('mousemove');
e.pageX = jQuery(window).width() / 2;

jQuery({pageX:e.pageX}).animate({pageX: 1000},
    {
        step: function(){
            console.log(this.pageX);
            e.pageX = this.pageX;
            jQuery('.mouseover').trigger(e);
        },
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'linear'
    }
);
```

Comment: You'll get (noticibly?) better performance by assigning `jQuery('.mouseover')` outside of `animate()`.