# How can I make the cursor of a user jump to a specific coordinate on the page when they hover over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a script that will change a user's mouse position when they hover over an image, like if I hover over the image, their mouse is dragged lower to a certain text, is there any way to do that?

Comment: could you add some code please?

Comment: pls search for similar issues on stack overflow, like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: @morels there is no mention of a textbox, simply an image hover (jump to on image hover) - maybe you should read the question..

Comment: you are right @RachelGallen, the pasted linked was wong. The correct (duplicate) link is: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Comment: @morels your link to q seems to provide answers that suggest it can't be done. I beg to differ

Comment: @RachelGallen it can't or people would hijack your cursor constantly...browser won't allow it. Your answer is misinterpreting OP's intent

Comment: @charlietfl the OPs question is pretty vague to begin with, I doubt you can definitively state what the OP wants, and I think that the scroll-to-hashtag answer that I have provided will adequately  suffice to meet his/her needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl. I've used small images. When you hover on them they'll scroll to different divs of text (not much text in the divs at the mo, but you get the picture)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scroll").hover(function(event) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#btm {
  background-color: #21b81e;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}
#mid {
  background-color: #2d80e8;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}
#tp {
  background-color: #c00;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}
img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div>
    <p><a id="top">Hover over an img:</a>
      <a href="#middle" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/4.jpg" alt="middle" title="middle"></a>
      <a href="#bottom" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/3.jpg" alt="bottom" title="bottom"></a>
    </p>
    <div id="tp">Top</div>
    <p><a id="middle">Hover over an img:</a>
      <a href="#top" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/11.jpg" alt="top" title="top"></a>
      <a href="#bottom" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/3.jpg" alt="bottom" title="bottom"></a>
    </p>
    <div id="mid">Middle</div>

    <p>
      Hello my name is rachel Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
      <br>
      <strong>Note that this paragraph has no scroll class, so when you hover over the images, it is not scrolled to, but you CAN add a scroll class anywhere (with a hashtag). </strong>
    </p>
    <p><a id="bottom">Hover over an img:</a>
      <a href="#top" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/11.jpg" alt="top" title="top"></a>
      <a href="#middle" class="scroll"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/4.jpg" alt="middle" title="middle"></a>
      <div id="btm">Bottom</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/Ltuktzek/)