# How to place the mouse pointer over submit button automatically in a login page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouse-cursor, mouse-position

The question might look silly, but I want to control the mouse pointer inside my web application / webpage. One of my client asked me this requirement of **Having the mouse pointer over the submit button automatically**, which will save some time in his opinion.

I have suggested to press **Enter** key. But still he is not convinced.

So, is there any possibility that i could control the mouse pointer location, at-least inside the browser?

I have tried something with **mousemove()** function, which only helped me to find when i move the mouse pointer.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){ //capture mouse movement event
  alert('Mouse Pointer Moved');
 $("#pageLayover").remove(); // remove our layover from the DOM
  });
```

Looking forward for the best solution.

Comment: you cant change users cursor position. you can use javascript to *simulate* this though. (it's a terrible idea- tell your client it's not possible to do)

Comment: May be i don't want to change the cursor position. but when the page loads, the mouse pointer has to be on the specific location **(over the submit button)**

Comment: ok...: > 'you can't change users cursor position. you can use javascript to simulate this though'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to control mouse position with Javascript. Here is a [mozilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=630979) discussing why