# How to make the cursor follow the element

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and I need the cursor to stay on the element when the element moves on screen. 
I have a list of elements and on click the elements rearranges and the clicked element changes position. 
If I need to click on the element again I have to move the cursor to follow the element. 
I want the cursor to change the position automatically to stay over the clicked element.

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve that. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752512/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by cursor? Hopefully, you don't mean the mouse location.

If that is the case, here's an idea, create an input, put your text inside, but theme this input like regular text, ex. removing the border of the input etc. This way when you click the text, the cursor will be displayed. Unless you click somewhere else, otherwise the cursor will stay there, blinking.

Comment: This is a comment, not a real answer.

Comment: No I really mean mouse location. Why do you hope I don't mean that? Think three squares <p> elements. I click on the one in the middle. It moves to the first position. I want the cursor (hand shape) to move with it so the square can be clicked again.