# Auto Cursor move like polar using javascript with html

Tags: javascript, html

We like to implement auto mouse move(cursor) using javascript with html like autoclicker polar(https://polarbytes-auto-clicker.en.softonic.com/).

**Is it possible mouse move like cursor using javascript with html?**

If yes, then what technology should I look into?

Please give me suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the mouse pointer to a specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot move the mouse cursor, as it would be a severe security breach.

Comment: although you are correct, you can create a click event without moving the cursor, which is what I think the OP is really after.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21720967)

Comment: @DarkMukke The question was "Is it possible mouse move the cursor using javascript?"; I answered "Javascript cannot move the mouse cursor." How is this not an answer? If this isn't valid, questions like these could never be answered because there is no real solution.

Comment: because after 1k rep i think you to be smart enough to read between the lines. and answer that technically it is not possible but you still know where the intent of the question comes from and provide a more detailed answer on how they may get their problem solved

Comment: @DarkMukke With all due respect, he is specifically asking to move the mouse using autoclicker software (which can do other things like move mice and press keys); to assume the question is different than what it is would make for a possibly incorrect answer. He didn't specify anything like "I want to be able to move it to buttons to click them", so I can't assume that's what he meant because the possibilities of what he really meant are many.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with web, you need to do this with local software. If you want to do this in javascript you can do this with nodejs. like this module https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

Comment: I am trying to run github robotjs(above mention link) while i am getting error, which says cannot find module './build/Release/robotjs.node', Please guide